# AnotherOperationInProgress when deploying multiple Azure virtual networks and subnets with ARM at once

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I want to deploy a virtual network setup with these vnets / subnets

- frontend

  - firewall
  - appgw
  - api
  - jump
- cluster

  - ingress
  - agents

each of the subnets is included in the `"resources": [...]` array of the corresponding virtual network and each of the subnets has the vnet as dependency like this:

```
            {
                "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
                "type": "subnets",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "name": "ingress",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[parameters('vnetNameCluster')]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefixIngress')]"
                }
            }
```

However when deploying the virtual networks, very often a conflict is raised:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AnotherOperationInProgress",
        "message": "Another operation on this or dependent resource is in progress. To retrieve status of the operation use uri: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/westus/operations/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?api-version=2020-04-01.",
        "details": []
    }
}
```

What dependency can I add to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some trial and error I avoided the conflict by adding the previous subnet within a virtual network as a dependency - hence the first subnet still only having a dependency on the virtual network:

```
            {
                "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
                "type": "subnets",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "name": "agents",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[parameters('vnetNameCluster')]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('vnetNameCluster'),'ingress')]"
                ],
```

Comment: Stumbled on this one when creating a set of subnets with the `copy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources syntax, one has to use serial mode otherwise the conflict will arise - you cannot deploy multiple subnets in parallel. Thanks,